# Собрать deb пакет Python проекта

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, debian, deb

Пытаюсь собрать deb пакет по вот этим гайдам:

- [How We Deploy Python Code](https://www.nylas.com/blog/packaging-deploying-python)
- [Как создать deb пакет?](http://qa-help.ru/questions/kak-sozdat-deb-paket)

У меня в `requirements.txt` лежат, помимо прочих, библиотеки: numpy, pillow, opencv-python .

Они мешают мне собрать deb-пакет.

Попытка собрать deb заканчивается на следующей ошибке:

> ```
> running build_ext
>
> ------------------------------------- Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
>
> OK    dh_perl    dh_link    dh_strip_nondeterminism    dh_compress   
> dh_fixperms    dh_strip    dh_makeshlibs    dh_shlibdeps
> dpkg-shlibdeps: ошибка: не удалось найти библиотеку
> libgfortran-3b85572a.so.3.0.0, необходимую для
> debian/image-processor/usr/share/python/image-processor/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
> numpy/.libs/libopenblasp-r0-135a2122.2.18.so
> (формат ELF: «elf32-i386»; RPATH: «»)
> ```

Есть и другие, похожие на эти, суть которых в ом, что сборщик  dh_shlibdeps ищет какой-то .so и не может найти..

Как исправить ошибку? 
Прежде не собирал deb пакеты, не так давно работаю в linux.

Спасибо!

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79505/discussion-on-question-by-stvlpotapov--deb--python-).